# Experiment for measuring flow rate vs diameter

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics

I am trying to establish the relationship between the diameter size of a pipe and the flow rate water. The main idea for my experiment would be to run water through pipes of varying diameter and measure the flow rate.

I was thinking of the following setup:

Water tap $>$ pipe $>$ Measuring device (like venturi meter)

In other words, the water would flow from the tap into the pipe. Then, I will try to measure the flow rate using something like a venturi meter. Or, I was also thinking of dropping something like a small particle on one end of the pipe and measure its velocity on the other end.

Would this setup be enough to complete the experiment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but the venturi meter costs money. Here is a way that costs much less: run the water out the pipe into a bucket, and let it run for a fixed time. then measure how much water is in the bucket after that much time. That will give you the average flow rate.

Please note that you will also need to know the source pressure at the tap, but water pressure gauges are easy to come by and not as expensive as a venturi meter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Just to confirm, The flow rate would simply be equal to $\frac{(Volume    of    bucket)}{time(in seconds)}$ right? Also, its fine if the pipe cross-section isn't completely filled with water right?

Comment: And why is the pressure at the tap important?

Comment: you want the pipe to be completely filled with water. You need to know the tap pressure so you can set it to exactly the same pressure in all your tests.